# How to calculate upload/download 3g speed in android application?

Tags: android

In my application, I need show upload/download 3G speed in current time.

Can you please help me how to solve this problem?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use facebook library for speed test https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

Comment: My idea is to upload/download a file to a server and measure time from uploading/downloading, but i don't know how to do this

Comment: facebook library calculates speed for you when you will send/receive data. you no need to do it by your self

Comment: thank you, i will try it after work. in my company, github is blocked